# os rename and listbox callback

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, rename

the purpose of this app is to rename every file 1 to a certain number then a new window opens up and i want the code to add a star at the beginning of the file that the user chooses

```
from tkinter import *
from typing import Collection
import os
 


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x200+700+300")

label1 = Label(text="Add directory")
label1.place(x=100,y=20)

entry1 = Entry()
entry1.place(x=300 ,y=20)

label2 = Label(text="enter the name")
label2.place(x=100 ,y=50)

entry2 = Entry()
entry2.place(x=300 ,y=50)

label3 = Label(text="enter the extention")
label3.place(x=100 ,y=80)

entry3 = Entry()
entry3.place(x=300 ,y=80)


directory = entry1.get()
name = entry2.get()
extention = entry3.get()

def main():

    directory = entry1.get()
    name = entry2.get()
    extention = entry3.get()
    folder = directory
    listbox_entries = [os.listdir(folder)]
    
    for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder)):
        dst = f"{name} {str(count)} {extention}"
        src =f"{folder}/{filename}"  
        dst =f"{folder}/{dst}"
         
        os.rename(src, dst)

btn2 = Button(text="rename",command=main,font="arial 22 bold")
btn2.place(x=150 ,y=120,width=200,height=40)


class Frames(object):
 
    def newWindow(): 
        newwin = Toplevel(root)
        newwin.title('New Window')
        newwin.geometry("200x500") 
        newwin.resizable(0, 0)
        labe = Label(newwin,text="Add directory")
        labe.pack()

        entr = Entry(newwin)
        entr.pack()
        def get():
            folder = entr.get()
            f = os.listdir(folder)
            liste = Listbox(newwin)
            for i in f:
                liste.insert(END,i)
            liste.pack()
            def fav():
                def callback(event):
                    aaa = event.widget.curselection()
                    os.rename(aaa,f"✰{aaa}")


            btn55 = Button(newwin,text="FAVORİTE",command=fav)
            btn55.pack()

        btn4 = Button(newwin,text="0",command=get)
        btn4.pack()


    
    def mainFrame(root):
        root.title('Open New Window!!!')
        root.geometry("200x200") 
        root.resizable(0, 0)
    button1 =Button(root, text ="✰", command =newWindow)
    button1.place(x = 30, y = 150, width=25, height=25)


root.mainloop()
```

the problem I'm having is at the line 74 it gives no errors or any input it basically does nothing .as I mentioned it above I want it to add a star at the beginning of the name that the files has.

Comment: Saying "line 74" means little here since no line numbers are visible. Please [edit] your question and add the error (along with the full traceback above that) to it.

Comment: All the `def fav():` does is define a nested function named `callback()` when it's called, only to then discard it when it returns — i.e. `callback()` is never called.

Comment: A **WARNING** to anyone trying to run this code: If you specify a folder and click on the rename Button, it can seriously mess-up the names of the folder was well as files in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class Frames` is defined but not called/instantiated anywhere.

`def mainFrame(root)` and the following `button1` needs to be dedented to outside the `class Frames` scope (I think). Also this function is not called by anything.

Suggest that before `button1` make an instance of `Frames` into a variable with
`variable = Franes()`
and use `command=variable.newWindow` in `button1`.

Better to have an initiation function in `class Frames`, ie `def __init__():` so that an instance is created when called. Then each function inside `Frames` becomes a class attribute and is accessible that way.

Suggest study `class` and `scope` in Python docs.

Comment: btw `__init__` doesn't create the instance, it is just called _when_ instantiating a class (as far as I remember `__new__` is what creates the instance)

Comment: *Calling* the class is what creates instances of it (via its `__new__()` method if it has one). Afterwards, if it has an `__init__()` method, that will be called to ***initialize*** it — but defining one not a requirement.

Comment: yeah thats true - bad choice of words on my part - thanks for clarifying.

Comment: ```__init__``` just  suggestion really and probably not what is wanted - the main point is that nothng happens with something if it is not called.

Comment: In that case you probably should have just focused on the main point. You're correct though about a `Frames` instance never being created, however its `newWindow()` method *is* being specified as the ✰ `Button`'s `command` option. It's also missing the `self` argument that all class methods receive automatically.

Comment: In tkinter the transfer of the 'self' parameter in the button command is passed implicitly.  So yeah there is a lot of change needed in this code - my intention is to offer a direction for a solution rather than the actual code.

Comment: You are mistaken, using `command=newWindow` will not implictly pass `self`. Regardless, I meant that the parameter must be explicitly declared in the method `def` — i.e. `def newWindow(self):`.

Comment: oh ok I was referring to my suggestion ```variable.newWindow```.  ```self``` still needs to be defined before the functions inside the class scope. This is usually done in ```___init___``` with ```self``` or any other name as the first parameter and then in the class scope this is called with ```self.newWindow()```. When called from outside class scope it would be ```Frames().newWindow()``` or ```variable.newWindow()```.

Comment: Just had a quick quick look at Python docs (3.10) and without function ```__init__``` it seems to me calling functions would need access to ```__dict__```,  ```__getattr__()``` or use of the ```__self__``` attribute.